# Windows batch script with multiple dependencies and possible asynch

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can you run a series of commands in windows where some depend on the completion of others and some can be launch at the same time asynchronously. Something like this:

command 1

when command 1 completes, launch commands 2

when command 2 completes, launch commands 3, 4 at the same time

when command 3 completes, launch commands 5, 6 and 7 at the same time

when command 4 completes, launch commands 8, 9 and 10 at the same time

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you layed out is very easy because each step is dependent on completion of only one predecesor. No polling is required.

You don't say what each of the commands are. At first I am going to assume they are all batch or console commands that inherently run synchronously. In other words, a batch file would not continue to the next command until the prior command was completed. In this case you only use the START command whenever you want to to launch the command asynchronously.

Your scenario could be easily implemented using 2 batch scripts. stepA.bat would initiate the entire process.

stepA.bat

```
@echo off
command1
start "" stepB.bat
command4
start "" command8
start "" command9
command10
```

stepB.bat

```
@echo off
command3
start "" command5
start "" command6
command7
```

If command1, command4, or command3 is a batch script, then it must be called using CALL, otherwise control will not be returned to the caller. For example, if command1 were "someScript.bat", then you would need to use `call someScript.bat`.

If command1, command4, or command3 are not console commands, but rather are commands that open their own window (like notepad.exe for example), then the command will run asynchronously by default and the batch file will continue before the command completes. You must use START /WAIT to make it synchronous. So if command1 were "notepad.exe", then you would need to use `start "" /wait notepad.exe`.

If command5, command6, command8, or command9 are not console commands (in otherwords they are asynchronous by nature), then you do not need to use START, though it doesn't hurt to do so.

You could have a scenario where you want to launch A1,A2 and A3 asynchronosuly, and then launch B only when A1, A2 and A3 have all completed. This will require some form of polling to determine when all three have completed. Each of the A processes would have to somehow signal when they are complete, and B would have to repeatedly poll and wait until it receives all 3 signals before proceeding. One form of signal could be the creation of a file, but there are many options.